# __nonzero__ magic method not functioning as expected

Tags: python, class

I have a Python class which I've been working with, and I wanted to define certain instances of the class as being NULL, i.e., they should evaluate to false in a conditional statement. By the documentation, the magic method that handles this is __nonzero__, which I implemented in my class. But now, I'm running into this odd behavior (X,Y are instances of my class).

```
X.__nonzero__()
Out[33]: False

Y.__nonzero__()
Out[34]: True

if X:
    print("X is True")
else:
    print("X is False")

Out[35]: X is True

if Y:
    print("Y is True")
else:
    print("Y is False")

Out[36]: Y is True
```

It seems as though my __nonzero__ method is being ignored. Why would this happen?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? In three, it should be [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__)

Comment: @Collin Oh... oops